# Search in list for values from the same list, sum values and del double entries

Tags: python

This is my string list:

```
[['AAA', '1000', '100'],
['AAA', '500', '25'],
['AAB', '0', '0']]
```

I want to read this list, AAA and check if it is twice or more often.
Then sum the numbers and remove the second, third or other double entries.
So the list shall look like

```
[['AAA', '1500', '125'],
['AAB', '0', '0']]
```

Perhaps someone can give me a good hint...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that the values are given as strings instead of ints (but you still want to add them like ints) makes it more difficult than necessary, but that's solvable with some careful `map` usage:

```
>>> values = [['AAA', '1000', '100'],
... ['AAA', '500', '25'],
... ['AAB', '0', '0']]
>>> [[
...     key, *(map(str, map(sum, zip(*(map(int, v[1:]) for v in values if v[0] == key)))))
... ] for key in set(v[0] for v in values)]
[['AAB', '0', '0'], ['AAA', '1500', '125']]
```

Doing it with a loop and a dict might look like this:

```
>>> totals = {}
>>> for v in values:
...     if v[0] not in totals:
...         totals[v[0]] = v
...         continue
...     for i, n in enumerate(v[1:], 1):
...         totals[v[0]][i] = str(int(totals[v[0]][i]) + int(n))
...
>>> list(totals.values())
[['AAA', '1500', '125'], ['AAB', '0', '0']]
```